# Get domain and subdomain in MVC .net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

How should I get the current domain and subdomain in MVC .net core2 in Startup.cs. I managed to do it in MVC3 and 4 but I cannot find anything in the documentation related to this. My startup file looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        string subdomain = //subdomain should come here
        string domain = //domain should come here

        app.UseMvc(route => CustomRouting.GetRouts(route,domain,subdomain));

    }
```

Comment: The routing is already clever enough to support any domain the site is being requested on. Why do you need these values there? And no, you cannot access them there, since they are values that are only valid during a request (and `Configure` lives outside of the request)

Comment: Because I would like to load the routes based on subdomains. This webapplication will handle multiple subdomains, and I have to distinguish them

Comment: I can't see why you need to check the domain here. If you are developing a multi-tenant app, it may be instructive too look at how something like [SaaSKit](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit) handles tenant domains.

Comment: `Because I would like to load the routes based on subdomains.` - Not possible. The routes are loaded 1 time at application startup, and subdomains are per request. It is possible to implement your own route to handle subdomain logic, but that logic belongs inside of the route (since it executes on each request), not in application startup (which only executes once per app pool restart).

Comment: Do you have a finite set of subdomains or are they dynamic to some extent?

Comment: they are dynamic, but I have 3 which must be handled separatly